# Define $T: U \times W \rightarrow V$, with $T(u, w) = u - w$. Prove $T$ is a linear transformation and show $range(T) = U + W$

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Let U and W be subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space V. Define $T: U \times W \rightarrow V$, with $T(u, w) = u - w$. Prove $T$ is a linear transformation and show $range(T) = U + W$

**Proving linear transformation:**

Multiplication:

Let $(u, w) \in U\times W$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$

$T(c(u, w)) = T(cu, cw) = cu - cw = c(T(u, w))$

Addition:

Let $(u_1, w_1), (u_2, w_2) \in U\times W$

$T((u_1, w_1) + (u_2, w_2)) = T(u_1 + u_2, w_1 + w_2) = (u_1 + u_2) - (w_1 + w_2) = T(u_1, w_1)
+ T(u_2, w_2)$

Thus $T$ is a linear transformation.

**Proving $range(T) = U + W$**

No idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that to prove two sets are equal, it's sufficient to show that each one is a subset of the other. So I would suggest first proving that if $v \in Range(T)$ then $v \in U + W$, then prove that if $v \in U + W$ then $v \in Range(T)$.

For the second part, remember that, for example, if $b$ is a scalar and $w \in W$, then $-bw \in W$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align} T((u_1, w_1) +c(u_2, w_2))& = T((u_1+cu_2), (w_1+cw_2))\\  &=(u_1+cu_2) - (w_1+cw_2)\\ &= T(u_1, w_1) +cT(u_2, w_2)  \end{align}$

$\begin{align} range(T) &=\{u+w  : u\in U,-w\in W\}\end{align}$